# Получить страницу с доп. инфой

Tags: c#, веб-скрейпинг

У сайта есть список, который изначально показан не полностью. При нажатии на "Показать все" идёт подгрузка остального списка. Как мне получить страницу с уже развёрнутым списком?

Сайт - http://www.rusprofile.ru/id/189505 (внизу в `Дополнительные виды деятельности (17)`).

Код:

```
public static string GetCode(string urlAddress) {
        string data = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null) {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            } else {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }
            data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Кликнул, посмотрел куда запрос идёт. Оказалось - сюда: www.rusprofile.ru/ajax.php?action=company_info&id=189505&data=okved.secondary - ну и в чём проблема второй запрос сделать и распарсить json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```csharp
string ID = "189505";
string url = $"http://www.rusprofile.ru/id/{ID}";
string urlJson = $"http://www.rusprofile.ru/ajax.php?action=company_info&id={ID}&data=okved.secondary";
```